# 16.04 - Slow login, no wallpaper, missing image icons in taskbar

Tags: unity, login, launcher, icons, desktop-background

As of about a week ago, my desktop has exhibited the following problems - all starting at once.

- After a cold boot or a restart I reach the login screen in a normal amount of time, but after entering my password there's a noticeable hitch, then I end up on a black screen with only a mouse cursor.
- If I leave it alone for a few minutes, the taskbar and launcher finally appear.
- Besides the taskbar and launcher, the desktop remains black (as if there's no longer a wallpaper set), but the computer is otherwise functional.
- All the icons in the top-right corner of the screen have a 'missing image' icon:

  [image: Taskbar]

As far as I know I didn't make any configuration changes at the time, besides perhaps installing updates.  Here's some system information; please ask if something else would be helpful.

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Unity 7.4.0
- Intel Core i3 3.3Ghz x 4 / 8GB RAM
- Gallium 0.4 on AMD TURKS (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)

Here is what I *think* is [the log of the last `apt` operation](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bc245aac0bb2e51c54a1962db2766cfd) before I started having trouble.  Right at the end it shows `Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly` - but I'm not sure what in particular it's referring to, or how to recover from it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the line say before the error you listed? Something like: "dpkg: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed."

Comment: I don't see anything like that - the gist I link to is pretty much all I've got.  The term.log.1 file doesn't show any errors, but it's probably notable that the last line before it quits is `Unpacking unity (7.4.0+16.04.20160906-0ubuntu1) over (7.4.0+16.04.20160715-0ubuntu1) ...`.

Comment: Interesting I've never paid attention to Unity but I just read  another AU question where the OP referenced Unity version 7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I'm certain of the root cause here, but just re-updating everything seems to have gotten things back to normal.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot
```

My best guess based on the logs is that something went terribly wrong while updating the window manager to `unity (7.4.0+16.04.20160906-0ubuntu1)` that at the very least caused a bunch of the built-in assets to go missing.  Another upgrade fixed the install.